# Check session if session expires,redirect them to particular page

Tags: 6

I have two types of users,`authenticated users` and `anonymous users`.It would be helpful if i could `redirect` a `logged-in` user to the login page once the `session` has expires.Now what i have is that, i stay at the same page which is a bit of `confidential` type of page.So i would like to check if `session` exists after a particular time period if possible and redirect the user if the `session` expires..